# How to force stop method exection from Callable<Object> call method

Tags: java

I have a method:

```
public class Datasource  {

    public void create() throws MyException{

     // can take more time than expected

    }
}
```

I want to add timeout to this method.

I tried:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MyException {
        runWithTimeout(new Datasource());
    }

    public static void runWithTimeout(final Datasource ds) throws MyException {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Callable<Object> task = new Callable<Object>() {
            public Object call() throws MyException {
                ds.create();
                return null;
            }
        };
        Future<Object> future = executor.submit(task);
        try {
            future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        } catch (TimeoutException tex) {
            throw new MyException("TimeoutException. Caused By", tex);

        } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
            throw new MyException("InterruptedException. Caused By", iex);

        } catch (ExecutionException eex) {
            throw new MyException("InterruptedException. Caused By", eex);

        } finally {
            future.cancel(true);
            executor.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

But create method is still running. How can I force stop it.

I can't modify `create()` method. So I can't  add `isInterrupted()` on current thread in `create()` method.

Comment: Simply put, there is nothing you can do.  Code which does not respond to interrupts is rogue code.  You cannot force it to stop.

Answer (score 0):

The `Future.cancel` call does not terminate the ongoing process. It's more like a hint for future Tasks that this one is cancelled. Besides that there is no guaranteed way to stop a `Thread` from a third party library. The only thing you can hope for is to iterate over `ThreadGroup` and call `interrupt()` on them and then *hope* that the ongoing `Thread` has a handling for `isInterrupted` and cancels itself.